# How can I enable the file upload button for the Line Details screen in Purchase Receipts?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to be able to upload an Excel file to populate the Line Details Smart Panel grid, but having no luck.

I've set the "AllowUploads" Mode Layout property to "true" - and it shows the icon - but it's always disabled:

[image]

I've also redefined the splits view in the BLC extension to add the following attribute:

[image]

I've also  tried to use a RowSelected event in the business logic to AllowUpdate - but there is no property in the "splits" view to enabled that.

Bottom line:  How can I enable this button and allow file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to add the PXImport attribute to the splits view.  One step you lack is to assign the Mode property name AllowUpload.  Afterwards, the upload button will appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my original post, I mentioned that I can get the icon to show up  (because I did add that AllowUpload - see above) - but it shows up as disabled all the time.  That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type on the PXImport attribute to this:

```
[PXImport(typeof(POReceiptLineSplit))]
```

This is because the PXSelect is selecting a POReceiptLineSplit record.